# Stock Spreadsheet - How to add new stock without using a cumulative total

Tags: google-sheets

I have a small restaurant and have two Google spreadsheets, Monthly Orders and Total Stock.

- "Monthly Orders" keeps a cumulative total of all dishes sold during a month.
- "Total Stock" is `=(0-Monthly Orders)+Starting Stock`
- "Starting Stock" is the total amount of a dish I started the month with.

My problem is when I add new stock. The only way I have been able to do it is by making a cumulative total of "Starting Stock+New Stock"

So if I start the month with 6 Butter Chicken for example. Then I sell 6 Buttern Chicken. Total Stock for Butter Chicken will equal zero. However, if I make 10 more Butter Chicken the only way I can keep the Total Stock number accurate is to change Starting Stock to 16.

However, I figure there must be a way of not using a cumulative total, and just enter the total of the new stock?

First time using this forum, so if you need further information, please let me know. In the meantime, I appreciate any help. Thanks. [Link to Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t8oK_2T9tgOYz6ubSZ70akKQb37ZuG91txfAU4R4J1Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you add the expected results on your example.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Maybe I'm missing something here but have you considered making a sheet for Production (duplicate and rename "Total orders"). So if you make 5 Butter Chicken on 3 December, then you enter 5 into cell D9 of the "Production" sheet. Then on "Total Stock" , in the "Stock Added Column, you reference the total in Production:Column AG.